# AS5048A SPI - 13bits instead of 14bits resolution

Tags: spi, encoder, stm32f4

I'm trying to make a driver for as5048a (spi) on STM32f405rg
This magnetic encoder is supposed to have 14bits of resolution :
[image]
and the read package shows that the 2 MSB are parity and error flags
[image]

So I'm masking them :

```
uint8_t rMSB=0, rLSB=0;
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 0u);
rMSB = SPI_read_byte(self->spi);
rLSB = SPI_read_byte(self->spi);
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 1u);
*buf = (((rMSB << 8) | rLSB) & ~0xC000);
```

But when reading buf, I only get values from 8192 (0x2000) to 16384 (0x4000).
Maybe someone has already face this problem and could explain what I'm doing wrong. 
EDIT : 
[image]
As said, the as50148a needs two transmissions here's what i do :

```
{


uint16_t command = 0b0100000000000000; // PAR=0 R/W=R
command |= reg;
command |=((uint16_t)spiCalcEvenParity(command)<<15);
// send register address to be read
uint8_t MSB = (command>>8) | 0xFF; // shift the upper 8 bits down
uint8_t LSB = command | 0xFF; // mask upper 8 bits

AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 0u);
SPI_write_byte(self->spi, MSB);
SPI_write_byte(self->spi, LSB);
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 1u);
/*
second command should be 0x0000 (nop) or clear flag (0x0001)
but when sending the second command, there's no angle returned.
thus by commenting this it gives me an angle from 0x2000 to 0x3FFF
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 0u);
SPI_write_byte(self->spi, 0x00);
SPI_write_byte(self->spi, 0x01);
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 1u);
*/

uint8_t rMSB=0,rLSB=0;
// read data
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 0u);
rMSB = SPI_read_byte(self->spi);
rLSB = SPI_read_byte(self->spi);
AS5048A_cs(&self->cs, 1u);

*buf = ((( ( rMSB & 0xFF ) << 8 ) | ( rLSB & 0xFF )) & ~0xC000);
```

Comment: Are you actually getting 0x4000? Or do you mean a maximum of 0x3FFF?

Comment: Please post your SPI_read_byte code. I suspect you are receiving more than one byte in each call, since your MCU is 32-bits and the sensor transmits data in 16-bit packets.

Comment: @Tyler If the variable to the left of the assignment is at least 16-bit long, the operation is perfectly valid (it is equivalent to multiplying rMSB by 256).

Comment: Also, take note that a read command takes two 16-bits transmissions to complete (four "SPI_read_bytes"), as explained in page 18 of the sensor datasheet.

Comment: What is your zero position? Also, please check the error bit and make sure it is reset for the problematic values.

Comment: This is a little broad, is it your magnetic coder that is expecting 14 bits and only getting 13? Or, your microcontroller is only producing 13?

Comment: uint8_t SPI_read_byte(){
return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(ctx->spi);
}

@Vicente, I've tried to read 4 bytes on the spi bus, but nothing interesting.
WhatRoughBeast I get 0x3FFF not 0x4000
StevieV Haven't looked on the oscilloscope to see how many bits are transmitted

Comment: interesting, I'm getting the same thing. for some strange reason, bit 13 is always high for me as well. It's possible that we are both doing the same thing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, I had the SPI mode wrong !
Be sure to be CPOL = 0 CPHA = 1 (on stm32f405rg)