# AS5048A and STM32F446RE SPI communication

Tags: stm32, spi, encoder

I am trying to get SPI communication working with my Nucleo-F446RE STM32 board and an AS5048A magnetic encoder. I am trying to read the angle register to get the angle value - however is seems to be spitting out random numbers.

I have read the datasheet and here are some key points:

- An SPI command is 16-bits long
- MSB is parity bit, and second is R/W bit (read is 1 and write 0)
- Once a read command is sent, it takes another transmission cycle to recieve the data from the register.
- Here is an image to better describe it[image]

[image]
[image]

On my Nucleo board in the STM32 IDE, I have configured my SPI module to be on SPI2 (I have checked to make sure connections are sound). I have also followed this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223426/as5048a-spi-13bits-instead-of-14bits-resolution) to set the SPI mode (for the AS5048A it uses Mode 1).

Here is my code:

```
  uint16_t cmd = 0b1111111111111111;
  uint16_t val;

  ... 
  ...
  ...

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(100);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GREEN_LED_GPIO_Port, GREEN_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
         HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, (uint8_t *)&cmd, 1, 100);
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
         HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, (uint8_t *)&val, 1, 100);
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_SS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

         angle = val & 0b0011111111111111;

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The read angle register is 0x3FFF (0b11111111111111) and since read command there is another 1, and one more for parity thus the command is 0b1111111111111111.

When I run this, I get rapidly changing values as shown:

11567
15497
12037
4089
15468
...

There is no indication that the value being shown is the angle from the encoder.

I have also tried lowering the SPI communication speed but no change.

Any ideas thanks :)

Comment: There are many already available drivers for Arduino, ...etc why don't you use them instead of starting from scratch?

Comment: You need to narrow the problem area. It has OTP you can read.  Data from OTP should be stable.

Comment: Yes, so reading from the OTP register also seems to give a garbage value.